# "API gateway" vs "MQ Manager"

Tags: api, rabbitmq, microservices

I'm new microservices and this maybe an incorrect question at all, but could you please explain whether "API gateway" and "MQ Manager" serve the same purpose or not? Or are this two completely different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different things.

**API gateway** is a facade over APIs exposed by multiple (backend) services. It provides APIs of granularity that's useful for end users, hiding the unnecessary (clunky on that level) APIs exposed by lower-level services.

**MQ manager** is a manager of managing queues, it's responsible for handling message-based communication. (These messages might be used for communication between services and/or clients, so here might be the confusion with API gateway).